# If $(a_n)$ is a limited sequence, $a_n\leq a_{mn}$ and $|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|\leq c_n$, then for which sequences $(c_n)$ does $a_n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ be a bounded sequence such that

$$a_n \leq a_{nm}$$

for every $n,m \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

What conditions do we need on $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ so that

$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq c_n$$

for every $n \in\mathbb{N}$ implies $a_n$ converges?

The [problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405634/ramsey-tur%c3%a1n-density-function-is-well-defined/405643#405643) I'm trying to apply it also has a further hypothesis, which is that there is $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that
$$a_{n-1} \leq a_n$$
for every $n$ nonmultiple of $k$.

I'd appreciate any help! Any help adding proper tags to this question would be great too.

Comment: My guess is that you meant to write *bounded* sequence.

Comment: If $a_n \le a_{nm}$ then ($m=0$) $a_n \le a_0$ at the same time ($n=1$) $a_1 \le a_m$. Which implies that your sequence is bounded by below and above by $a_1$ and $a_0$.

Comment: @GáborPálovics It doesn't make much difference but I didn't mean to include zero. Sorry.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n < \infty$ implies for $m<n$ that $|a_m - a_n| \le \sum_{k=m}^\infty c_n \to 0$. I don't see any way to apply this to a sequence of integers(?) nor do I see how to relate this to Fekete's lemma

Comment: Well one sufficient condition would be $c_n \to 0$, it would imply that the series is Cauchy and therefore it is convergent.

Comment: @GáborPálovics the counterexample for that: let $c_n=1/n$, $a_n=\sin( H_n)$ where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$. Then $a_n$ is bounded and $|a_{n+1}-a_n| < 1/n $ but $a_n$ is not convergent. OK, this doesn't include the $a_n\le a_{nm}$ condition and if you dont want bounded you can just use $a_n = H_n$...

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry, it is not integer. It is real. I edited the question with the right context.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for your comment. I think your idea is probably the best we could get without any information about this sequence $(c_n)_n.$